# Метод Trace.TraceInformation(string)?

Tags: c#, .net, юнит-тесты, отладка, логирование

Для чего и как используется этот метод?

```
[TestMethod]
public void Q_GetAllCustomers_NoExc()
{
     foreach(var i in context.GetAll<Customer>())
     {
          Trace.TraceInformation($"{i.FirstName} {i.LastName}")
     }
}
```

Куда попадёт string, который я передаю этому методу. И как это вообще связано с TDD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это встроенное средство отладки, трассировочное сообщение.

У вас есть [конфигурируемый](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) через app.config (или вручную) [список слушателей трассировочных сообщений](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.listeners%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Им и доставляется полученная строка.

Например, вы можете направить ваши трассировочные сообщения [в файл или на консоль](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [положить в системный event log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogtracelistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [отправить по сети](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx092chh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) или [положить на web-страницу](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpagetracelistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

В случае, если вы запускаете проект из-под Visual Studio, ваши трассировочные сообщения слушает IDE, и показывает их в окошке Debug.

В случае, когда вы запускаетесь не из-под Visual Studio, трассировочные сообщения уходят системе (если вы не отконфигурировали по-другому). Вы можете их видеть при помощи, например, утилиты [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx).

С TDD не связано никак.

Answer (score 3):

> Куда попадёт string, который я передаю этому методу.

Если компиляция проходила при включенном TRACE, то 
зависит от того какие TraceListener'ы подключены. 
Посмотреть можно так:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

for(var i=0; i < Trace.Listeners.Count; i++) { 
    Console.WriteLine(Trace.Listeners[i].GetType().Name);
}
```

при выполнении кода в C# interactive выводится `DefaultTraceListener`.

---

Коллекцию Trace.Listeners можно менять, и например, если требуется выводить информацию в файл, после запуска приложения вызываем:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(@"c:\temp\trace.txt"));
```

Дальше, где-бы ни находился вызов `Trace.TraceInformation("test");` в файл выводит `test` вместе с именем процесса. 

Формат вывода можно настроить и выводить время, идентификатор потока и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к ответу @VladD добавлю, что в случае с запуском теста из-под Visual Studio, вся отладочная и трассировочная информация также доступна в тест аутпуте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]